# AngularJS form, hide invalid style when init?

Tags: forms, angularjs

How can I show invalid style only when user type something invalid instead of showing them on init (page load)?

The angularJS form inputs has all red invalid CSS style when init, **demo here**:

http://plnkr.co/edit/iDcG8J?p=preview

What I want is that it only turns red when user type in something invalid, instead of showing the invalid red style when init.

When init, I hope the inputs are all normal black style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ng-required` and `ng-change`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput) to do that: http://plnkr.co/edit/LxJGK3?p=preview

In the template:

```
<input  type="text" 
        data-ng-minlength=3 
        data-ng-model="form.min" 
        ng-required="minTouched" 
        ng-change="minChanged" />
```

In the controller:

```js
function ($scope) {
  $scope.minTouched = false;

  // ...

  $scope.minChanged = function () {
    $scope.minTouched = true;
  }
}
```